# How can I stop tables appearing in Enterprise guide?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm writing procedure for other users to run in Enterprise guide based on SAS 9.3. It logs various bits of information to a table. Is there any way to stop this table appearing in the process flow?

NB This is almost all done using "User written code" steps. Unfortunately the setting in the menu (see vasja's answer below) does not seem to affect UWC steps.

(I've seen this: [Tell SAS not to add newly generated tables on the Process Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720171/tell-sas-not-to-add-newly-generated-tables-on-the-process-flow) but I'm using 9.3 so it doesn't work!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague (twitter.com/binarytrain) figured out a solution.

Tables are always added to EG projects in 9.3 if, at the end of the code step, the library in which it exists is still assigned(1). So, in the question above, the trick is to clear the libname at the end of the code step.

This can further be used to "discourage" - not stop - users from meddling with temporary tables.

- Create a folder in &sasworklocation called _work
- Register it as a library
- Save any temporary tables in this new library
- Clear this library at the end of the code step

At this point the temporary table is inacessible without running a libname statement

- Re-registered the library when the table is required again.

(1) Even if it's assigned using a different name, so this won't work for pre-assigned libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In EG 5.1:
go to Tools - Options, select Result General:
deselect Automatically add output to the project tree.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The only way I can get objects to not be added is to delete them at the end of the code step - good practice for live use, but putting debug switches in is a pain.